# Erro ao se conectar ao banco de dados [WinForm/C#/SQL Server]

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, connectionstring

Meu professor do curso de C# ensinou uma nova técnica para a gente hoje, one não é preciso informar a ConnectionString propriamente dita, o programa iria até a pasta de documentos e pegaria o arquivo .mdf (SQL Server) e abriria a conexão com ele, mas venho apresentando o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro que eu tive]

Estes são meus códigos:

1. Fui até o Program.cs do arquivo no Visual Studio e acrecentei as as seguintes linhas:

> string x =
>   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
>               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", x);

2. Na classe que armazena a ConnectionString, coloquei a seguinte linha:

> public static string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=**|DataDirectory|/baseFarmaciaZyX.mdf**;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

A parte em negrito seria o diretório do arquivo mdf, que é pego pelo "DataDirectory".

Gostaria de saber o que aconteceu, já que quando foi testado durante a aula, com os mesmos códigos, deu certo.

(O arquivo .mdf se encontra na minha pasta "Documentos")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Garanta que a instância LocalDb está rodando

O Visual Studio automaticamente sobe uma instância local do SQLServer express (Indicado na `connectionString` por 'LocalDB'). Portanto para a sua conexão funcionar, o Visual Studio deve estar aberto. Pode ser o problema se você está executando o executável compilado direto do Windows.

### Verifique que o arquivo .mdf existe no diretório.

`Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` representa a pasta 'Meus Documentos' no Windows. Mas para garantir cheque o resultado da expressão abaixo no seu código (via Debug ou imprimindo para o console). O arquivo 'baseFarmaciaZyX.mdf' deve existir dentro dessa pasta:

```
string x = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

### Caso ainda não funcione

Sugiro que você siga instruções da tela cujo print você mostrou na pergunta. Muitas coisas podem dar errado em uma conexão com um DB.

Boa sorte!